ORA-01446 trying to select rowid from a view with a union clause
I have two databases with the same table, all my data split between these bases and I have a view with union clause
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  MY_UNION_VIEW AS
     SELECT col1, col2 from tableX@db_link1
         UNION 
     SELECT col1, col2 from tableX@db_link2

and its working well, until we  get select with rowid
select col1 from MY_UNION_VIEW  - OK
select * from MY_UNION_VIEW  - OK
select rowid, col1 from MY_UNION_VIEW   - ERROR (ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.)
the problem is - I cannot change the rowid select , its an external APP, I can only change the view definition and can create new objects in my DB
Any ideas how can I avoid it ? I know rowid its an address representation of row in db, and "rowid of view" makes no sense, but I have to return rowid from on of these physic tables (tableX@db_link1 or tableX@db_link2 by selecting it with PK: select rowid where <PK conditions> )
I tried to add rowid as column and use UNION ALL instead of UNION:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  MY_UNION_VIEW AS
     SELECT rowidtochar(rowid) AS "rowid", col1, col2 from tableX@db_link1
         UNION ALL
     SELECT rowidtochar(rowid) AS "rowid", col1, col2 from tableX@db_link2

I`m using rowidtochar cast here, because if i tried this:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  MY_UNION_VIEW AS
     SELECT ROWID AS row_id, col1, col2 from tableX@db_link1
         UNION ALL
     SELECT ROWID AS row_id, col1, col2 from tableX@db_link2

I got another error - ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression error

I don't think you can avoid the ORA-01446, even with union all, and if you could fix the other errors. (ORA-01790 looks odd; are the DBs different versions and/or character sets?) Apart from anything else, you can't include a ROWID alias in the view definition, and the final query wouldn't be able to use it. You could maybe use a materialised view; but then the ROWID value would be from that (or its underlying table), not your base tables.

Can you try: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  MY_UNION_VIEW AS
SELECT rowidtochar@db_link1(rowid) AS row_id, col1, col2 from tableX@db_link1
UNION ALL
SELECT rowidtochar@db_link2(rowid) AS row_id, col1, col2 from tableX@db_link2
?

You cannot have a parent query refer to rowid from a view if that view involves more than one table. Oracle has no idea which table to pull it from! You can of course alias it in a UNION ALL (doing so in UNION makes no sense, as it would force uniqueness across the set so the sort would accomplish nothing) but then your parent query would need to refer to the alias. You are not permitted to use "ROWID" as an alias, and the lowercase and double-quoted "rowid" would be a different alias that the parent query would have to match exactly (lowercase and double-quoted).

@AlexPoole for pure test I created table in one db, then I connected to another and create table as select * from table@db_link1 - so tables are the same. ith maWterialised view it works correct, but i cannot afford it, as u said theres different rowid

They might still be different versions and/or have different character sets. It's moot anyway, since even if you fix those errors, you're still stuck. If you can't change the external application query to either not get rowid at all or or to get an alias instead, I don't think you can do what you want here, (Also curious what it wants it for, as it won't know which table  each rowid is from, they could change, and you could possibly even get duplicates...)

What version of the database are you using?  I can't reproduce on current versions
SQL> create or replace view vvvv as
  2  select rowid r , empno from emp@pdb21a
  3  union   -- (same with union all )
  4  select rowid r , deptno from dept@pdb21a;

View created.

SQL> select * from vvvv;

R                       EMPNO
------------------ ----------
AAAwjtAAMAAAAFuAAA       7369
AAAwjtAAMAAAAFuAAB       7499
AAAwjtAAMAAAAFuAAC       7521
AAAwjtAAMAAAAFuAAD       7566
AAAwjtAAMAAAAFuAAE       7654
AAAwjtAAMAAAAFuAAF       7698
AAAwjtAAMAAAAFuAAG       7782
AAAwjtAAMAAAAFuAAH       7788
AAAwjtAAMAAAAFuAAI       7839
AAAwjtAAMAAAAFuAAJ       7844
AAAwjtAAMAAAAFuAAK       7876
AAAwjtAAMAAAAFuAAL       7900
AAAwjtAAMAAAAFuAAM       7902
AAAwjtAAMAAAAFuAAN       7934
AAA0ASAAMAAAAF7AAA         12
AAA0ASAAMAAAAF7AAB         10
AAA0ASAAMAAAAF7AAC         11
AAA0ASAAMAAAAF7AAD         13
AAA0ASAAMAAAAF7AAE         21
AAA0ASAAMAAAAF7AAF         22
AAA0ASAAMAAAAF7AAG         42

21 rows selected.


You still can't do select rowid, empnp from vvvv though - and it seems they can't change the external query to do select r, empno....

exactly, you can select * from vvvv, but if i trying to get select rowid from vvvv - its not working
